# Android Studio cannot resolve symbol 'android'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-import

I am doing a project in Android Studio and today I saw that suddenly all my code has errors and even the line:

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;

has error: cannot resolve symbol android

any suggestions why this might have happened?

Comment: did you try Build->Clean Project?

Comment: no what do you mean by that?

Comment: At top of Android Studio there is the "Build" option, click there and then select "Clean Project".

Comment: I actually just saw that the folder libs is not loaded in my project for some reason. however it is there in the right path in the directory. Right now build is disabled for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please ensure you have mention in your project grades it has been tested and working fine**

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
  ...
}
```

**clean your project and rebuild again and wait till android studio make indexing and loaded all resource some time due to system it will slow.
please comment if you found something else. happy coding :)**

Answer (score 0):

1st update your SDKs ( Android tools SDK & Google play service)

in your build.gradle "modules" include this code in your dependencies

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:<version>
```

where  is the latest version available...my version at the time of this answer is 11.0.4

Answer (score 0):

Please try as follows

1. Exit Android Studio
2. Back up your project
3. Delete all the .iml files and the .idea folder
4. Relaunch Android Studio and reimport your project

or

1. Exit Android Studio
2. Back up your project or rename your project
3. Clone new project

Answer (score 0):

> solved this issue by -> clean project - > save all - > close all tabs ->
> Close entire project ->
> Reopen it again.

The issue solved